# XCode can't find base SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode

XCode 3.2.3 Beta does not allow building for below 3.2.

I opened a project that was made in an earlier XCode. 
For some reason, the base SDK is reported as missing even after changing it to 4.0.
Other projects from earlier XCode do not have this issue.

What can I do?

Comment: May be SDK path is not properly, try searching SDK in finder and set path in Xcode project.

Comment: Editing the `.pbxproj` in your `.xcodeproj` might help.  In the `XCBuildConfiguration` section there are values for `SDKROOT`.

Comment: @Evadne Wu - Any specific ideas? I just started looking into that.

Comment: @Evadne Wu - Post as the answer, that did work!

Comment: Go Here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks

Comment: Search for file named  project.pbxproj in your app project folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Happy to hear it worked!

—

Editing the `.pbxproj` in your `.xcodeproj` might help. In the `XCBuildConfiguration` section there are values for `SDKROOT`.

Answer (score 17):

If you can't choose the SDK at the top left of x-code you have to first 
set the base SDK in the project settings. 
Project -> Edit Project Settings. 
Then choose the "General" tab. 
At the bottom you can choose "Base SDK for all Configurations:"

Comment: Normally this would work. However, projects ported from XCode in the iOS 3.x SDK to the iOS 4 SDK may not show the base SDK option. In that case you will, like me, have to follow Evadne Wu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question has more details on the situation: [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks)

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to edit the Base SDK setting for each of the different build configurations, then the error went away. You need to fix "Release", "Debug" and any others.